# Condition variable blocks on main thread

Tags: c, multithreading, race-condition

I want to use condition variables to launch at most N thread to process all files one one huge directory (1M files).

The code seems to work but after some times, it blocks in main thread. Below the frustrating code:

```
void* run(void* ctx)
{
    clientCtx* client = (clientCtx*)ctx;
    printf("New file from thread %d: %s\n", client->num, client->filename);
    free(client->filename);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clientFreeMutex);
    client->state = IDLE_STATE;
    pthread_cond_signal(&clientFreeCond);
    printf("Thread %d is free\n", client->num);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clientFreeMutex);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    pthread_t client[MAX_CLIENT] = {0};
    clientCtx ctx[MAX_CLIENT] = {0};
    DIR* directory = NULL;
    struct dirent* element = NULL;

    /* Initialize condition variable for max clients */
    pthread_mutex_init(&clientFreeMutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&clientFreeCond, NULL);

    /* Initialize contexts for clients */
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < MAX_CLIENT; cnt ++)
    {
        ctx[cnt].state = IDLE_STATE;
        ctx[cnt].num = cnt;
    }

    directory = opendir(argv[1]);

    while((element = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&clientFreeMutex);
        int cnt;
        for (cnt = 0; cnt < MAX_CLIENT; cnt++)
        {
            if(ctx[cnt].state == IDLE_STATE)
            {
                ctx[cnt].filename = strdup(element->d_name);
                ctx[cnt].state = BUSY_STATE;
                pthread_create(&client[cnt], NULL, run, &(ctx[cnt]));
                break;
            }
        }
        /* No free client */
        if (cnt == MAX_CLIENT)
        {
            printf("No free thread. Waiting.\n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&clientFreeCond, &clientFreeMutex);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&clientFreeMutex);
    }
    closedir(directory);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

What is the problem? thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Warning you use the value of *readdir* in separate threads without any protection against the multi-threading, so when you (try to) *printf* `client->file->d_name` may be you are doing at the same time *readdir* in the main thread modifying the saved result, this has an undefined behavior.

You need for example to save a *strdup* of `element->file->d_name` in *main* and save that string in the *clientCtx* rather than the `struct dirent *`, and of course to free it in *run*

Note also a *closedir* is missing at the end of *main* even in this case it is not a real problem (just do to remember for your other programs).

Comment: thanks for your advices but it does not fix the behavior. I update the first message.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem: launched threads were not joined and pthread_create finally returned an error code with errno message set to "Could not allocate memory". The signal was never sent and the main thread was then blocking.

I fixed this creating a new state for already launched threads and adding a join in main loop.